# I want to do so if you press a linked line it insted of sending you to a website i makes an alert

Tags: javascript, html

My current code:

```html
<a href="chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz" target="_blank">DONT PRESS ME!</a>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, usually:

```html
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="alert('Hello')">DONT PRESS ME!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think you want something like this. When some user clicks a button or linked line it should be trigger an alert rather than redirecting that user to another linked site. So, the code should be like this. This code contains both HTML and JavaScript.

### HTML

```
<a href="" id="linkUrl">DONT PRESS ME!</a>
```

### JS

```
var link = document.getElementById("linkUrl");
link.onclick = function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Warning!");
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know about your progress.

Comment: Shouldn't you add an `e.preventDefault();`? I'm curious if you'll still be redirected to the other site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggstion @SophiaKoulen . I didn't notice that. Without using e.preventDefault(); the page still refreshing in each click.